# Telnet connection stops bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, telnet

I have a bash script where I continuously read from a text file the hosts and port and create a connection to check for the status.

My code is:

```
while IFS=";" read -r host ports
do
    eval "arr=($ports)"
    for port in "${arr[@]}";
    do
        echo "connecting to $host on port $port" >> output.txt
        timeout 5s telnet $host $port
        exit_status=$?
        if [[ $exit_status -eq 124 ]]; then
            echo "$host on $port has timed out" >> output.txt
        else
            telnet $host $port >> output.txt
        fi
    echo "---------------------------------------------" >> output.txt
    done
done < "$1"
```

The first `if` is to check if the connection timeouts. 
That works as expected.

In the `else` - `telnet $host $port`, I am checking that if the connection does not timeout, then `telnet` into the remote host to see if the connection was ***successful*** or ***refused***.

But, when the connection is ***successful***, the script **exits** abruptly by spitting out:

```
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I want it to write to the output file, "connection is successful" and continue reading the remainder of $1.

When connection is refused, the script does not exit; it works as expected -- it continues to read from $1 and continues running the instructions.

I also, am in a situation where I cannot use `netcat`.

Comment: What do you mean, "file status"? You've determined that the port didn't time out, but what's the point of the `telnet` connection? Are you hoping to establish a connection and execute a command?

Comment: `telnet $host $port >> output.txt </dev/null`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am trying to check if the connection to the host has been established or refused and write that result to the output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [roaima pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491353/117549), the telnet commands will soak up stdin input, which you've redirected into the `while` loop. As a result, as soon as one of the telnet connections is successful, your `while` loop will end because `telnet` gobbled up the rest of the input that you were expecting to be fed to `while`.

The immediate solution to that problem is to redirect `telnet`'s input, most simply from /dev/null, as [commented by Cyrus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491350/telnet-connection-stops-bash-script#comment901746_491350): `telnet host port >> output.txt < /dev/null`.

To differentiate between a successful connection and a (presumably >5s delayed) refused connection, I've captured the output from the telnet command and checked for the "`Connected to`" message. If that message is present, we assume success; otherwise: failure.

The main changes to your script were:

1. redirecting both `telnet`'s stdin from /dev/null
2. quoting all the variables
3. capturing & checking the `else` - `telnet` output for comparison

The updated script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=";" read -r host ports
do
    eval "arr=($ports)"
    for port in "${arr[@]}";
    do
        echo "connecting to $host on port $port" >> output.txt
        timeout 5s telnet "$host" "$port" < /dev/null
        exit_status=$?
        if [[ "$exit_status" -eq 124 ]]; then
            echo "$host on $port has timed out" >> output.txt
        else
            output="$(telnet "$host" "$port" 2>&1 < /dev/null)"
            case $output in
              (*Connected\ to\ *)
                echo "connection is successful to $host $port" >> output.txt
                ;;
              (*)
                echo "connection was refused to $host $port" >> output.txt
                ;;
             esac
        fi
        echo "---------------------------------------------" >> output.txt
    done
done < "$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `telnet` commands will attempt to read from the remains of your `$1` file, whatever that may be. So your loop may get executed an unexpectedly fewer number of times.

I'm not sure what input you were expecting to provide to `telnet` though.

Incidentally, if you have it installed you'd be better off using `netcat` (sometimes known as `nc`). It won't solve it change the input issue but it is usually a better tool for this kind of scripted interaction.

Comment: I am trying to write to that output file if the telnet connection was successful (that is connected) or has been refused by remote host

Comment: this is the whole script that I have provided.
On <timeout 5s telnet $host $port> i am checking if the connection times outs. 
Then if it does not I use <telnet $host $port >> output.txt> in the <else> to check if the connection has been refused by remote host, or connected. And I write the telnet output to the output file. But the problem is when the connection is successful, the script exits.

Comment: Also, I am not in a scenario where i can use nc

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this but it's for remote access. If I could only get the redirect to work it would be way cleaner.

Remote:

```
ssh -q USERNAME@HOSTSERVER 'echo -e "\x1dclose\x0d" | telnet REMOTESERVER PORT'|grep Connected>/dev/null && printf "PASSED\n"||printf "FAILED\n"
```

Local:

```
echo -e "\x1dclose\x0d" | telnet REMOTESERVER PORT|grep Connected>/dev/null && printf "PASSED\n"||printf "FAILED\n"
```